# Oracle - SQL Distinct Select on aliased columns

Tags: sql, oracle, select, distinct, alias

I am selecting columns with aliasing, like:

```sql
select t.name, t.surname from table t where some conditions...;
```

Now I want to add **distinct** function on a particular column. So, if I were to select this without an alias, it would have looked like:

```sql
select distinct(name), surname from table;
```

but what if I want to write select query with ALIASED column names?

`select distinct(t.name)` does not work, nor `select t.distinct(name)` does.

Comment: you cannot use distinct on a particular column. distinct is always aplied to the whole row. could you make an example for the desired result to clarify what do you try to achieve

Comment: The fact that it's aliased is irrelevant. `select distinct(t.name)` 'works' but the brackets are redundant, it's the same as `select distinct t.name`. If the query didn't give the results you expected, or gave an error, you need to give more details, perhaps with a more concrete example.

Answer (score 3):

How shall I write select query on ALIASED column names?

You cannot write select query on aliased column names.

Aliases are useful for the following:

1. There are more than one table involved in a query
2. Functions are used in the query
3. Column names are big or not very readable
4. Two or more columns are combined together

Comment: I'm not sure what 'select query on aliased columns' means... you can alias the columns, as you said and the OP is already doing. Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: Yes, this isn't actually accurate, but I don't want to downvote due to the -1 rep cost

Answer (score 1):

Using `DISTINCT` keyword on the very first column of `SELECT` clause. For example the code below works where we want to apply DISTINCT on specific column. In the first case specific column is NAME and in latter case specific column is SURNAME.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(T.NAME), T.SURNAME FROM TABLE T WHERE ...;
SELECT DISTINCT(T.SURNAME), T.NAME FROM TABLE T WHERE ...;
```

In case you want DISTINCT applied on both the column us following technique:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(T.NAME), T.SURNAME FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT(T.SURNAME), T.NAME FROM TABLE T WHERE ...;
) T
```

Comment: Distinct is always applied to all expressions in the list, [as the documentation says](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF55272). All three of your queries will give identical results, and the third just does an unnecessary subselect and an extra sort...

Comment: Yes absolutely correct all three queries will give identical results. I put my focus on use of DISTINCT keyword on aliased column.

Answer (score 0):

Distinct is not a function, it's a [clause in the `select` statement](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF55272):

> Specify DISTINCT or UNIQUE if you want the database to return only one
>   copy of each set of duplicate rows selected. These two keywords are
>   synonymous. Duplicate rows are those with matching values for each
>   expression in the select list.

You cannot apply `distinct` to a single expression (column) in the query, only across the whole row.

It isn't really clear what you want to have in your result set. You're implying you have the same `name` with multiple `surname` values; if you only show each `name` once you need to determine which `surname` (and other fields) to show. One option is to group and pick the min or max value:

```
select t.name, min(t.surname)
from table t
where ...
group by t.name;
```

If you have multiple columns in your real query an analytic `row_number` or `dense_rank` might be more appropriate, or there's the `keep` clause. It depends what's you're trying to do though.

Or if you *only* want the `name` field and are not showing the `surname` at all now, then simply:

```
select distinct t.name
from table t
where ... ;
```